# Get a service bean from Grails Holders class

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

I'm trying to update a plugin to Grails 2.4. Thus I have to replace the deprecated ApplicationContext class by the newer Holders class.

But I'm having some problems getting a service bean from the Holders class.

Running the code below:

```
import grails.util.Holders;

def myService = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.myService

println myService
println myService.getClass()
println myService.serviceMethod()
```

It prints something like:

> grails.plugin.my.MyService@1e5cd54d
>   Exception thrown
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at ConsoleScript2.run(ConsoleScript2:6)
>     at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)

It throws a NullPointerException when I call both: the "getClass" method and the "serviceMethod" method.

I tryed to see what's happening by debugging from eclipse too and I can observe "myService" variable being set to an object. When I click on it I can see it's String representation just like printed above. But I can't see anything inside the object. This service' class has member variables, but I can't see them on debug. It's like uf they were'nt there.

Can someone explain me what is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: why are you not using the dependency injection facility from grails? Like for example when creating a controller just adding a class attribute "def myService" which is autowired via name.

Comment: Because I'm trying to access this bean from a non grails artfact class (src/groovy). So autowire is not available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Holders`, and avoid pulling in dependencies. Use dependency injection, it's a Good Thing.

Your `src/groovy` class is probably called from a controller, service, Quartz job, or some other Grails artifact that supports DI, right? If so, inject this service there, and when you call your src/groovy class, pass it as a method argument, or inject it once in a constructor or a setter.

Even if it's not called from a Grails artifact it's likely easy to get access to the service. E.g. a servlet can access the `ServletContext` and it's simple to access the `ApplicationContext` from there.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answer. 
Actualy this class is suposed to be called from outside my plugin. Then I don't think it's a  good idea to have it initialized from the class that is calling it.
About the ServletContext part, how different it would be from acessing the ApplicationContext from the Holders class?

Comment: Why not a good idea? You write the plugin, so you define the API and usage rules. This would not be likely to be that much of a burden. You could also register your src/groovy class as a Spring bean (a singleton if possible, prototype if it's stateful, and then either way you can use DI). Using the ServletContext and ApplicationContext you're still re-inverting control and pulling, but if that's the only way then that's what you need to do. The problem with `Holders` is that is has exactly the same problem that the deprecated/removed holders had.

Comment: Well, I'd like to avoid the setup approach. I like the bean one though. If I could make this class a prototype bean, that would be great <*insert a meme here*>. But is it possible given there's no "resources.groovy" file in the plugin hierarchy?

Comment: Of course - a plugin can do anything an app can do and a few things that apps can't (or can't do conveniently, e.g. web.xml editing and custom artifacts). Put bean registrations in doWithSpring in the plugin descriptor, and use the same bean builder syntax as in resources.groovy

Comment: Well, it seems that turning that class into a bean would change the way I instantiate it. I already have this plugin running on an application. I'd like to to upgrade it to grails 2.4 without making any changes on the that application if possible. I think creating a grails service to instantiate and initialize that class may be a great improvement for a future version of the plugin but, for now, I just need to get stuff working. Do you have any idea how I can get access to that service statically?

Comment: Worst-case scenario - use Holders, I'm just saying that it's unlikely that you need to do that. Aren't these classes called directly or indirectly from an artifact that can use DI?

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for taking so long. I've been trying to find an easier way to solve this problem but turns out that changing the way my plugin deals with this dependency may be the best solution. Thank you very much for helping.